# Bubblesort Issue C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, bubble-sort

I have a small issue to get my bubble sort algorithm to run correctly in C# but I can't figure out my mistake.

For ex. Random Input:
23,20, 17, 11, 17, 18, 4, 1, 16, 11
Output
20, 17, 11, 17, 18, 4, 1, 16, 11, 23

```
public class BubbleSort
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a BubbleSort Program!");
        Console.WriteLine("Pease enter the amount of Numbers to sort:");
        int userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] randomNumbers = new int[userNumber];                      //Create an array of a random lengh (user decides)
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < userNumber; i++)
        {
            randomNumbers[i] = r.Next(1, 25);                        //fill array with random numbers between 1 and 25
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < userNumber; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + randomNumbers[i]);                  //write down the Array numbers unsorted
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("");




        bool getSwapper = true;
        while (getSwapper)                                          //Runs as long as there are numbers to sort
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < randomNumbers.Length; i++)          
            {
                int tempNumber = 0;
                if (randomNumbers[i - 1] > randomNumbers[i])
                {
                    tempNumber = randomNumbers[i - 1];              //safe the bigger number in a temp var
                    randomNumbers[i - 1] = randomNumbers[i];        //overwrites the bigger number with the smaller one
                    randomNumbers[i] = tempNumber;                  //overwrites the smaller with the bigger one
                    getSwapper = true;                              //sets swapper to true
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + randomNumbers[i]);              //lists the sorted numbers of the array
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your issue ? You mention small issue but what is your issue ? Sample input to reproduce that issue.

Comment: You never set `getSwapper` to `false`. Also bubble sort requires multiple passes to completely sort the list

Comment: You need to set the getSwapper to false before the for loop.

Comment: As others have said, you're failing to reset the swapper flag and you're outputting the "sorted" output after (each/one) pass when you need multiple

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* issues:

1. You should reset `getSwapper` to `false`.
2. You print the `randomNumbers` *too early* when they are not sorted yet.

**Code:**

```
    bool getSwapper = true;
    while (getSwapper)                                          //Runs as long as there are numbers to sort
    {
        getSwapper = false; // <- reset getSwagger or we'll have an infinite loop;            

        for (int i = 1; i < randomNumbers.Length; i++)          
        {
            int tempNumber = 0;
            if (randomNumbers[i - 1] > randomNumbers[i])
            {
                tempNumber = randomNumbers[i - 1];              //safe the bigger number in a temp var
                randomNumbers[i - 1] = randomNumbers[i];        //overwrites the bigger number with the smaller one
                randomNumbers[i] = tempNumber;                  //overwrites the smaller with the bigger one
                getSwapper = true;                              //sets swapper to true
            }
        }
    }   // <- You should end while here

    // <- It's the right time now (when getSwapper is false) to print the results

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(" " + randomNumbers[i]);              //lists the sorted numbers of the array
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: @Ceraxes Sure you could have figured it out. Bubble sort is a simple algorithm, and I believe you are fully capable of understanding it. All you needed to do was spend some more time on it, perhaps a combination of [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and using your IDE's debugger ([directions for Visual Studio here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)) to step through the code line by line would have gotten you there.

Answer (score 1):

@Dmitry Bychenko already gave the correct answer that contains what you were missing.

I want to share a simple bubble sort algorithm with you that I just did, fewer lines of code, less complex. It may help you to master this algorithm.

**Code:**

```
var arrayValues = new[] { 99, 12, 11, 300, 400, 10, 9, 3, 6, 5, 7, 8};
for (var mainLoop = 0; mainLoop < arrayValues.Length; mainLoop++)
{
   for (var innerLoop = mainLoop + 1; innerLoop < arrayValues.Length; innerLoop++)
   {
       if (arrayValues[mainLoop] <= arrayValues[innerLoop])
       {
         continue;
       }

       var temp = arrayValues[mainLoop];
       arrayValues[mainLoop] = arrayValues[innerLoop];
       arrayValues[innerLoop] = temp;
  }
}
```